# Npm Please try using this command again as root/administrator

Tags: windows, node.js, npm

I've been desperately trying to install modules using node.js but it always fails getting packages with npm.

I logged in as Administrator and used powershell/cmd with "run as administrator". I also had problems with the registry so I used npm set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/

I tried everything... it just drives me nuts.

Here are the errors:

**npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.**

```
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "generator-knockout"
npm ERR! cwd D:\Sergiu\Knockout Test
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! path D:\Sergiu\Knockout Test\node_modules\generator-knockout\node_modules\yeoman-generator\node_modules\tar\node_modules\block-stream\block-stream.js
npm ERR! fstream_path D:\Sergiu\Knockout Test\node_modules\generator-knockout\node_modules\yeoman-generator\node_modules\tar\node_modules\block-stream\block-stream.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno 50
npm ERR! stack Error: EPERM, lstat 'D:\Sergiu\Knockout Test\node_modules\generator-knockout\node_modules\yeoman-generator\node_modules\tar\node_modules\block-stream\block-stream.js'
npm ERR! fstream_stack C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fstream\lib\writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: EPERM, lstat 'D:\Sergiu\Knockout Test\node_modules\generator-knockout\node_modules\yeoman-generator\node_modules\tar\node_modules\fstream\LICENSE'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM, lstat 'D:\Sergiu\Knockout Test\node_modules\generator-knockout\node_modules\yeoman-generator\node_modules\tar\node_modules\fstream\LICENSE']
npm ERR!   errno: 50,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   path: 'D:\\Sergiu\\Knockout Test\\node_modules\\generator-knockout\\node_modules\\yeoman-generator\\node_modules\\tar\\node_modules\\fstream\\LICENSE',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'File',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: 'D:\\Sergiu\\Knockout Test\\node_modules\\generator-knockout\\node_modules\\yeoman-generator\\node_modules\\tar\\node_modules\\fstream\\LICENSE',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'FileWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack:
npm ERR!    [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\fstream\\lib\\writer.js:284:26',
npm ERR!      'Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)' ] }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
```

Comment: My node_modules folder was set to readonly! Right-click properties and fix it. :}

Comment: I had a similar error to this, but on Mac, and fixing it involved switching access on both node_modules and my usr/local/bin folder from "Read only" to "Read & Write"

Answer (score 121, accepted):

It turns out that you don’t have to run the command again as Administrator, and doing so won’t fix the problem.

Try:

1. `npm cache clean` first.
2. If that doesn’t fix things, take a look in `%APPDATA%\npm-cache`, or if you’re using PowerShell, `$env:APPDATA\npm-cache`.

After cleaning the cache, you may still be left with remnants.  Manually remove everything in that directory, and try again.  This has always fixed things for me.

As @Crazzymatt was mentioning, as of the npm@5 version and up, we need to use `npm cache verify` instead of `npm cache clean`. Or else you will get an error as preceding.

> npm ERR! As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid. If you want to make sure everything is consistent, use 'npm cache verify' instead.

(Source: [MSDN Blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matt-harrington/archive/2012/02/23/how-to-fix-node-js-npm-permission-problems.aspx))

Comment: As of NPM5 you can run "npm cache verify" which worked for me

Comment: Sometimes `npm cache clean` will give you a warning so you may want to force it to clean by doing `npm cache clean --force`

Comment: Just running the command (eg `npm install --save xxx`) again worked for me.

Comment: try : npm cache verify

Comment: For my case I had to reboot my machine after clearing the %APPDATA%\npm-cache folder. Windows 10.

Comment: Was able to use PowerShell to configure NPX.  GitBash and Command Prompt would not work.

Answer (score 49):

I solve it running as administrator cmd.
Cleaning the cache 

`npm cache clean -f`

And then try to install the package again

Comment: I did that, but it does not work. I ran the command as administrator as well.

Comment: this worked for me on windows 10 - run as admin didn't solve the problem

Answer (score 19):

You should run cmd.exe as administrator.

Follow the following steps:

- Click Start, click All Programs, and then click Accessories.
- Right-click Command prompt, and then click Run as administrator.

Answer (score 17):

Here is how I fixed this on my Windows (7) Dev. environment. 
I assume the following...

- You are Running  *Command Prompt*, *Git Bash*, *Cmder* or your favorite Terminal, as an **Administrator** by right clicking
- Privileges Permissions have been granted for ***Read/Write*** (i.e chmod -777)

**Okay, let's get to it:**

1. Update any packages where a version check is returning a warning *("npm WARN"..)* for example...

   **npm update -g npm**

   **npm update -g graceful-fs**
2. Next we want to **force** a *cache clean*. This is flagged by an *'--f'* or *'-f'*..

   **npm cache clean --f**
3. In *Widows Explorer* search for the following path

> > %APPDATA%\npm-cache

And **Delete** it's contents

4. Start a fresh instance of your **Terminal**, remembering to *'Right-Click' and 'Run as **Administrator***', install the packages again.

Hope this helps someone!!

Comment: I've tried a lot of solutions that worked for other individuals, but damn....no success for me on npm install --save-dev webpack.  A couple of weeks ago, it worked fine and I'm doing a tutorial over again with all the same commands, but not permissions or whatever will not let me install.    I found this:   https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/18380

Comment: npm install --no-optional webpack worked for me AFTER I rolled back to npm i -g npm@5.3

Comment: This solution should be further up for Windows 7 users. Worked for me.

Comment: **Deleting contents of npm-cache worked for me.** Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I was already running the Node Command Window as Administrator. As mentioned by many above, the following command with --f (force) solved my issue.

> > npm cache clean -f

After the Cache Clean, the install was flawless. [See the screenshot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtNLd.png)

Comment: I sure hope you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 7):

[I had to login into npm to resolve this issue](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/adduser).

`npm login`

Comment: any of the above solutions fixed this problem. When I logged in it just works. Thanks

Comment: This is the solution for me.Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using TFS or any other source control for your project that sets your checked in files to readonly mode, then you gotta make sure package.json is checked out before running npm install. I've made this mistake plenty of times.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and I've fixed the error by cleaning the cache:

```sh
npm cache clean -f
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, what I did to solve it was ran the cmd.exe as administrator even though my account was already set as an administrator.

Answer (score 4):

Try following steps

**1. Run this command on Terminal or CMD** - `npm cache clean`

**2. Go to this folder on windows `%APPDATA%\npm-cache` And delete folder which you want to install module (Ex:- laravel-elixir) or if you are using PowerShell, $env:APPDATA\npm-cache**

**3. Then Run your command `EX:- npm install laravel-elixir`**

Comment: If this doesn't work go to `%APPDATA%\npm` and delete both `ng` file and try it.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I fixed the problem in Windows. I was trying to install the CLI for Angular.

1. Turn off firewall and antivirus protections.
2. Right click the nodejs folder (under Program Files), select Properties (scroll all the way down), click the Security tab, and click all items in the ALLOW column (for All System Packages and any user or group that allows you to add the “allow” checkmark).
3. Click the Windows icon. Type cmd. Right click the top result and select Run as Administrator. A command window results.
4. Type npm cache clean. If there is an error, close log files or anything open and rerun.
5. Type npm install -g @angular/cli (Or whatever npm install command you are using)
6. Check the installation by typing ng –version (Or whatever you need to verify your install)

Good luck!
Note: If you are still having problems, check the Path in Environmental Variables. (To access:  Control Panel → System and Security → System → Advanced system settings → Environment variables.) My path variable included the following:
C:\Users\Michele\AppData\Roaming\npm

Comment: Thanks @tigerRose.  Great instructions. Seemed to help me make progress.

Comment: Finally, "Turn off firewall and antivirus protections" back on

Answer (score 2):

`npm cache verify`

Try for newer versions of npm.

I'm using v 5.5.1 and it's working fine.

Answer (score 2):

This is the flow often happens in this case. You run a command with no admin rights, you get message `npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.`. Then you open one more CLI(cmd, powershell, bash or whatever) and don't close the previous CLI. It appears you have 2 prompts opened in the same directory. And until you close CLI which runs with no admin rights you will be continuously getting `npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.` **So close CLI which runs with no admins rights** before running a new one.

**NOTE**: a lot of IDE has embedded CLI(Visual Studio, VS Code etc) so please close the instance of IDE as well

Answer (score 2):

For those doing this on a MAC. Simply put sudo in front of the command. It will ask you for your password and then run fine. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

What helped me on Windows 10 was just ticking off "Read Only" of project `node_modules`.

Comment: Felt sketchy, but this worked for me, while `npm cache clean` didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I messed with this problem 2 times and tried all suggestions here with mediocre success.

- First time I tried (and succeeded luckily) by:

  1. delete the node_modules folder in your project
  2. `npm clean cache -f`
  3. check your `%APPDATA%/npm-cache` and delete everything if not empty
  4. start the terminal as administrator (in my opinion, it isnt a problem of rights, but it wont hurt if you do so)
  5. `npm install` and then `npm update`
  6. you will get errors, **just install every module that throws an error manually and step by step try to eliminate everything whats wrong**

**However, this method is quite frustrating and not working everytime. So try this:**

- Second time I had no luck with the steps above, so I **tried to completely reinstall npm and it failed. So I thought there must something be wrong with my node.js installation.** My team is running 6.10. and I had the 6.11. and tried it with the 6.10. with no luck.

  1. So I completely wiped everything off my system. Deleted all node modules, checked every path where node or npm could be and cleaned my system.
  2. **Then I installed newest 8.1.3**
  3. Deleted my project and cloned it to a complete different directory.
  4. Now I installed and updated everything with `npm install` `npm update`
  5. Then I compiled with just 2 modules missing and installed them manually

Tadaaaaa, its working now. So all in all it was a problem with node.js. **I recommend to everyone who runs into this problem: Try different node versions! And clean ABSOLUTE everything.**

Answer (score 1):

As my last resort with this error I created a fresh windows 10 virtual machine and installed the latest nodejs (v6). But there was a host of other "ERRs!" to work through.

I had to run `npm cache clean --force` which ironically will give you a message that reads "I sure hope you know what you are doing". That seems to have worked.

It doesn't solve the issue on my main Dev machine. I'm canning nodejs as I found over the last few years that you spend more time on fixing it rather than on actual development. I had fewer issues with node on linux ubuntu 14.04 if that's any help.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the global npm-cache and/or running my cmd line as admin did not work for me. Also, as of npm version 5.x.x, it supposedly recovers from cache corruption by itself.

This did work:

**1.** Deleted the node_modules folder in my current project.

**2.** Deleted the package-lock.json in my current project

**3.** Installed the new package. In my case: `npm install bootstrap@next --save`

**4.** Ran `npm install` for my current project.

Everything now works. In general, nuking node_modules and package-lock.json usually fix these "no apparent reason" bugs for me.

### EDIT

I just had the same problem again. But I noticed that everything was installed correctly even though it threw the error after I had followed the steps outlined above. So I could just run `ng serve` (for Angular), and everything worked.

This sure is a weird error...

Answer (score 1):

As a hack,

Check if the folder path it is complaining exists or not.
If not, try creating them manually and rerun the installation, after clearing the cache

I had success with this, when running the installation from command prompt as an Administrator didn't work

Answer (score 1):

> $ npm cache clean
>   npm ERR! As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid. If you want to make sure everything is consistent, use 'npm cache verify' instead.

I tried running `npm cache verify` with admin rights and it worked after that.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, if your `package.json` is not too big you can do this:

- Signout then signin.
- Delete `node_modules`.
- `npm install` again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which steps worked for me. But these are my steps to get rid of this error:

1. Updated Node.js
2. Ran ***npm cache clean*** command in Command prompt ( With
   some element of doubt for cache presence)
3. Ran ***react-native init*** in
   command prompt as Administrator (on Windows OS), hoping works well
   with ***sudo react-native init*** on Mac OS

Comment: I tried your advice, but when I got to step 3 -->>  running reactive-native init in command prompt <<--  apparently I don't have that program installed -. Next - I searched my system using start menu Search - nothing comes up. Next, I googled it, and GOOGLE suggests "react..." (not "reactive...").   Can someone maybe explain how to install or use REACTIVE-NATIVE - or- REACT-NATIVE ???  Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo. It's react-native, not reactive-native

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answers, clean npm cache and make sure the cache folder is empty, then run npm install several times. Each time the error message comes for different packages, and the final time (after X attempts) it succeeds.

1. Run `npm clean cache --force`
2. `cd %APPDATA%\npm-cache` (or `cd $env:APPDATA\npm-cache` for PowerShell)
3. `del *` to delete everything in the folder
4. Go back into the project folder and run `npm install` several times until it succeeds. Notice that the error messages come for different packages every time.

Answer (score 0):

**WHAT WORKED FOR ME**

I ran Command Prompt as Administrator.  This helped partially - as I no longer got the error, "Please try using this command again as root/administrator". I was trying to install Cordova.  To do it successfully, I also had to do the following:

(1) "npm update node", plus...

(2) I also  added the  " -g "  in the >>npm install cordova<<. In other words, type this:   >>npm install -g cordova<<

**~~~ FOR WINDOWS 8.1 ~~~**

**"RUN AS ADMINISTRATOR" COMMAND PROMPT**

For windows 8.1, I don't have an ACCESSORIES group when I click START > ALL PROGRAMS.  But I do have that older -- but trusty and reliable -- START BUTTON and START MENU - thanks to the free Classic Start Menu app.  So, with that installed....

ALTERNATIVE #1:

```
1. Type "cmd" in the SEARCH BOX at the bottom of the START menu.  
2. When cmd.exe shows up in the top of the search results, right click it and select RUN AS ADMINISTRATOR.
```

ALTERNATIVE #2 If you already have a Command Prompt window open and running - and you want to open another one to Run As Administrator:

```
1. Locate the Command Prompt app icon in the Taskbar (usually along the bottom of you screen unless you have moved it a different dock/location).
2. Right click the app icon.
3. Now, right click "COMMAND PROMPT" and select RUN AS ADMINISTRATOR.
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

1. Close the IDE
2. Close the node terminals running ng serve or npm start
3. Go to your project folder/node_modules and see you if can find the package that you are trying to install
4. If you find the package you are searching then delete package folder
5. In case, this is your 1st npm install then skip step 4 and delete everything inside the node_modules. If you don't find node_modules then create one folder in your project.
6. Open the terminal in admin mode and do npm install.

That should fix the issue hopefully

Answer (score 0):

FINALLY Got this working after 4 hours of installing, uninstalling, updating, blah blah.

The only thing that did it was to use an older version of node  v8.9.1 x64

This was a PC windows 10.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in react native project, and **Expo is running**, then **close it**.

Re-install the package, and everything should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Also remember to end all other [npm](/questions/tagged/npm) commands e.g. `npm run dev-server`.

Comment: That should really be a comment. It gives additional helpful info, but doesnt solve the question.

Comment: @GhostCat It is a possible solution, so it should be an answer!

Answer (score 0):

A solution that worked, is to close all PowerShell and cmd instances. Start PowerShell/cmd again as administrator and things seem to work.

This can happen if you're doing react-native and the node.js cmd is open in the background.

Answer (score 0):

On windows 10,
`npm cache clean --force` and `npm cache verify` did not work for me. 
Tried to delete cache folder and file with administrator permission, did not work. 
The **process-explorer tool** helped me finding that `Node.exe` is holding on the cache file. I killed the process and tried to clean, worked.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem while executing the "npm publish" command.

Then I checked the error log, and solved this by executing "npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org" command. The obvious reason for this problem is that I set up another registry.

So, if you are in the same situation as mine, try setting the registry to official one.

Answer (score 0):

#docker answer

```
FROM node:lts-alpine3.17
RUN addgroup app && adduser -S -G app app
RUN mkdir /app && chown app:app /app
USER app
WORKDIR /app
COPY --chown=app:app . .
RUN npm install
ENV mongoURL=***
EXPOSE 8092
```