# nodemon bin/www works, nodemon app doesn't and throws error

Tags: node.js

When I run `nodemon bin/www` inside my app, it works perfectly, when I try to run `nodemon app`, it throws this error:

```
'\"node .\bin\www\"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I believe this happened after I received a notification from nodemon today to run `npm install -g nodemon` to update the nodemon library, after the installation, I got this error:

```
Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
```

I tried to run the cmd as administrator, again, the same problem. Any solution?

Answer (score 2):

step 1: run `npm install -g nodemon`

step 2: verify installation `npm list -g nodemon`

Now you can run the app by two ways

```
nodemon ./server.js localhost 8080
```

> Any output from this script is prefixed with [nodemon], otherwise all output from your application, errors included, will be echoed out as expected.

2nd just type `nodemon`

> If you have a package.json file for your app, you can omit the main script entirely and nodemon will read the package.json for the main property and use that value as the app.
>
> With a local installation, nodemon will not be available in your system path. Instead, the local installation of nodemon can be run by calling it from within an npm script (such as npm start) or using npx nodemon.

or

> It turns out that you don’t have to run the command again as
>   Administrator, and doing so won’t fix the problem.  Try

`npm cache clean first.`

check this for more detail

https://www.npmjs.com/package/fixmynode

[command against as root administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22325031/npm-please-try-using-this-command-again-as-root-administrator)

[how-to-fix-node-js-npm-permission-problems](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/matt-harrington/2012/02/23/how-to-fix-node-js-npm-permission-problems/)

Comment: When I run `npm uninstall -g nodemon` to uninstall it and then run `npm install -g nodemon`, it's throwing this error: `Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.` but apparently, it IS installing it.

Comment: `npm list -g nodemon` returned this: ``-- nodemon@1.12.0` and running `nodemon ./app localhost 3000` didn't throw any error, however, `localhost:3000` didn't work in the browser.

Comment: Also, `npx nodemon` threw the same err and browser didn't execute `localhost:3000` by using `npx nodemon ./app.js localhost 3000`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting this error because you did not install it as a global module. Try to install nodemon using the -g flag.

```
$ npm install -g nodemon
```

Comment: As I said, I installed nodemon using `npm instal -g nodemon` and it threw `Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.` error

Answer (score 0):

Install the nodemon module globally using

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

Also install the module in the package in your project where the package json is present using

```
npm install nodemon -save
```

Check if the nodemon is present in the json list.

Now run the js file using any of the following

```
nodemon 
nodemon app.js
nodemon app
```

Comment: `npm install nodemon --save` is still throwing the same err: `Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.` and it just didn't save the package inside the package.json file.

Comment: If its ubuntu, then login as root adminsitrator using su command

Comment: No it's windows 10.

Comment: use run as administrator

Comment: I did, the same problem. I ran cmd as administrator

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command line in an windows environment (1st cd to your apps root directory):

```
nodemon ./bin/www
```