# npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator for Ionic

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm

Im all ready read this [Stack Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22325031/npm-please-try-using-this-command-again-as-root-administrator)  , but its not work for me ,
 how to fix it,
 im try to more than 1 hours fix to this error

Thanks

> D:\Mobile Application\Ionic\myApp>npm install ion2-calendar moment
>   --save npm ERR! path D:\Mobile Application\Ionic\myApp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules npm ERR!
>   code EPERM npm ERR! errno -4048 npm ERR! syscall scandir npm ERR!
>   Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'D:\Mobile
>   Application\Ionic\myApp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules' npm ERR! 
>   { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'D:\Mobile
>   Application\Ionic\myApp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules' npm ERR!
>   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir \'D:\Mobile
>   Application\Ionic\myApp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\'',
>   npm ERR!   errno: -4048, npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM', npm ERR!   syscall:
>   'scandir', npm ERR!   path: 'D:\Mobile
>   Application\Ionic\myApp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules' } npm
>   ERR! npm ERR! Please try running this command again as
>   root/Administrator.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\Hp
>   Probook\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-11-09T08_23_38_831Z-debug.log

Comment: Does 'Hp Probook' user have privilege to run this?

Comment: yes sir , always display this error  try running this command again as root/Administrator. but last week its working fine

Comment: Can you try force install "npm install --force <package>"

Comment: ok sir I'll try it

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install --force
```

Has fixed it for me.