# How can i run NPM Commands in VSCode terminal?

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code

i'm working on NPM terminal in VSCode as git and i installed an extension to support NPM but didn’t work and i just got that error

> 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

**EDIT**

i already installed node.js , i just want to work in the regular command prompt rather than node.js cmd and i got errors but it worked well when i open cmd as an admin after adding 'C:\Program Files\nodejs' to the path. now how i work with npm in cmd without opening it as an admin ? i think it’s a permissions issue tho.

Comment: Install Node.js from (https://nodejs.org)

Comment: [Node.js tutorial in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-tutorial)

Comment: i’m already added it, i used to work in the node.js command prompt but i want to work in regular cmd and i face a problem. i think it is about permissions.

Comment: Maybe you installed Node before as Administrator, that's why it's requiring the same privileges. You can try to re-installing it on a non-Admin (?) account or check the solutions from [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22325031/npm-please-try-using-this-command-again-as-root-administrator).

Answer (score 0):

What version do you have? It sounds like node is not installed.

Try to run `npm -v` to identify the version?

Comment: no it’s installed. i added nodejs to the Path and it worked well in regular command prompt but with the administrator privilege. how i make it worked without opening it as admin ?

Comment: if you run npm -v what do you get?

Answer (score 0):

You can run npm commands in a VSCode terminal the same way you would run them in any terminal:
`npm <command>`

This is assuming npm is properly installed.

Regarding the error you reported, maybe check this out:
['npm' is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992723/npm-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-bat)